# Android - Relative layout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I am trying to make a layout for an activity using RelativeLayout.
What I am trying to achieve is this:

[image]

I have no trouble with A & B:

```
<ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/B"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/B"
            android:layout_above="@+id/A"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp" />
           <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/A"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/credit"
            android:background="@drawable/A" 
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
```

How can I get C and D to be a above and on the sides of B?  (Please Notice that all elements are centered, so there is margin on both sides of the screen).

10x!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can use `android:layout_alignLeft="@id/B"` for example, to align the left of an element to be in the same position as the left of element B.

Perhaps for element C you could try `layout_above="@id/B"` and `layout_alignLeft="@id/B"`